# Objective-C: Getting notification names from all NSDistributedNotificationCenter notifications?

Tags: objective-c, nsnotifications

I'm sure I had a tool that could log all system wide notifications but, not being able to find it, I'm writing my own.

So the documentation says I set up the observer by calling:

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver
           selector:(SEL)notificationSelector
               name:(NSString *)notificationName
             object:(NSString *)notificationSender
```

…but I don't want to listen to any one notification or object in particular so I set those values to nil. So far so good, I know when notifications are being broadcast.

But how do I get the names of the unknown notification and senders once they've been received? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:):

> The method specified by notificationSelector must have one and only one argument (an instance of NSNotification).

Therefore:

```
-(void)observerMethod:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  NSLog( @"%@", notification);
}
```

The `name` is a property of the passed notification. The sender is usually the property `object`. (It is not really the sender, but if somebody else is the sender, the object will be more interesting.) You can retrieve additional information from the `userInfo` property.

BTW, take care: The selector in this example is `observerMethod:`, not `observerMethod` (colon included).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's right there, as clear as day in the documentation! I'm so used to scanning the old format docs that I'm missing the obvious.